# XFCE window placement settings resetting

Tags: linux, xfce

I prefer all my windows to be centered when created so I went to **Window Manager Tweaks » Placement** and set `Maximum size of windows to trigger smart placement` to *Max (large)* and also checked `At the center of the screen.`

This works fine until I do a reboot when the settings appear to not have changed but new windows aren't placed at the center anymore (but in empty spaces on the desktop instead [default behavior I think])

Is there a way to fix this?

P.S. Issue occurs in both Xfce 4.8 and 4.10.

Comment: I have still the same problem with XFCE 4.16.. Very stupid issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too, this is how I got around it:

1. Find out which xfwm4 theme you're using with the "Window Manager" section on the settings manager.
2. Suppose it's "Zukitwo", edit the file `/usr/share/applications/Zukitwo/xfwm4/themerc` with your preferred text editor (you'll need root privileges).
3. Comment out or delete the line `placement_ratio=20`
4. Log out and log back in. It should be fixed now.

This `placement_ratio` variable corresponds to the slider on the Window Manager Tweaks settings. Its default value is 20, and the max is 100.

For some reason, some themes include this option in the `themerc` file and it overrides the value set by the user upon login.

Maybe this is not your case, but it's worth a try!

Lourenço

Comment: Theme files are now stored in `/usr/share/themes/`. But anyway, the `placement_ratio` is already NOT present in the `themerc` file. This will not fix the problem!